# Unittest simulate reading a yaml file with a mock

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I try test a function which reads a file and returns the content of the file or returns none if the file is not found.

```
def read_yaml_from_cwd(file: str) -> Dict:
    """[reads a yaml file from current working directory]
    Args:
        file ([type]): [.yaml or .yml file]
    Returns:
        [type]: [Dictionary]
    """
    path = os.path.join(Path.cwd().resolve(), file)
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        with open(path) as f:
            content = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
            return content
    else:
        return None
```

This is my test:

```
from unittest import mock, TestCase
from project import fs

class TextExamples(TestCase):

    def test_read_yaml_from_cwd():
        with mock.patch('os.listdir') as mocked_listdir:
            mocked_listdir.return_value = ['test-config.yml']
            val = fs.read_yaml_from_cwd("false-config.yml")
            assert val == None
            val2 = fs.read_yaml_from_cwd("false-config.yml")
            assert val2 != None
```

I guess I am fundamentally doing something wrong with these tests and what these mocks do. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Why are you mocking `os.listdir` when you are actually calling `os.path.join`, `os.path.isfile` & `open` in the function? You also need to mock `yaml.load`

Comment: If you mock away all of this, there's not much that remains to actually be tested, though if you just want to test if it returns `None` if the file does not exist I guess that would be sufficient. If you want to test more of the fs related stuff you may want to use something like pyfakefs instead (Disclaimer - I'm a contributor to pyfakefs).

Comment: Hm okay so how would you then write a test for this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility to test this is to patch both `os.path.isfile` and `open`. To patch open, there is already a special mock function, [mock_open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open), which gives you the possibilty to set the contents of the mocked file. This means that you don't have to mock `yaml.load`, as this will return the mocked file content. This could look something like:

```py
from unittest import mock, TestCase
from unittest.mock import mock_open

class YamlTest(TestCase):

    @mock.patch("builtins.open", mock_open(read_data="data"))
    @mock.patch("os.path.isfile")
    def test_read_yaml_from_cwd(self, patched_isfile):
        # valid file case
        patched_isfile.return_value = True
        result = read_yaml_from_cwd("some_file.yaml")
        self.assertEqual("data", result)

        # invalid file case
        patched_isfile.return_value = False
        result = read_yaml_from_cwd("some_file.yaml")
        self.assertEqual(None, result)
```

In this case you test that the function returns the file content if you pass a valid file name, and `None` for an invalid file name, which is probably all you want to test here.

For completeness, and because I mentioned it in the comments: using [pyfakefs](https://pypi.org/project/pyfakefs/4.5.3/) instead would replace the file system with a fake file system, which you can handle like a real filesystem, in this case it could look like:

```py
from pyfakefs import fake_filesystem_unittest

class YamlTest(fake_filesystem_unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.setUpPyfakefs()
        self.fs.create_file("some_file.yaml", contents="data")

    def test_read_yaml_from_cwd(self):
        # valid file case
        result = read_yaml_from_cwd("some_file.yaml")
        self.assertEqual("data", result)

        # invalid file case
        result = read_yaml_from_cwd("non_existing.yaml")
        self.assertEqual(None, result)
```

This makes sense if you have many filesystem related tests, though in your case this would probably be overkill.

*Disclaimer*: I'm a contributor to pyfakefs.

Comment: thank you very much for your effort! I appreciate that a lot and will work through that